# How to record audio file using HTML 5 in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have searched a lot on this but all i found is this audio recording is only possible in google chrome.

Can you please guide us how to record and play recorded file in IE using HTML 5 ?

Thanks
-Vivek Deshmukh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't. You'll need to use Flash or something.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, IE is not really HTML5 ready yet, at least not for more advanced operations like audio recording. WebKit browsers such as Chrome or Safari are much more up to speed in that regard.

Which version(s) are you using/testing?

Comment: I am using IE 10. If not supporting then any other workaround for this ?